# How to regex one word from escaped and closed parenthesis?

Tags: perl

I am trying to get "loginuser" value from this line. Please  suggest

```
my $ln = CN=xuser\\,user(loginuser),OU=Site-Omg,OU=Accounts_User,OU

    if (/ln: (\S.*\S)\s*$/)
       { print $1; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ln = qq{CN=xuser\\,user(loginuser),OU=Site-Omg,OU=Accounts_User,OU};

print $1 . "\n" if $ln =~ /\(([^)]*)/
```

Things to note

I have used strict and warnings to show any errors in the script( would have been very useful for your original)
I have used `qq{...}` to quote the original string
I have ended the line with `;`
I have performed the regex match on $ln instead of `$_` using `$ln =~ ...`
I have written correct regex to get the match.